# How much time of unemployment after PhD in order to still be competitive in postdoc application

Tags: postdocs

So I uploaded my PhD thesis about a month ago. I am trying to switch academic fields at the moment, and I applied to about 20 postdocs. However I am considering the possibility I may not get in for this application cycle, which would mean roughly another year. I was wondering how long can you be unemployed without your CV becoming uncompetitive. I am just balancing whether after this cycle I should give up and go to industry or whether I should keep grinding.

I am applying to earth sciences actually. My original affiliation is physics.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I strongly suggest continuing to apply, 20 jobs is very low in my experience (I am assuming from your name you are going into math, which is my field.) Many postdoc jobs are only just now getting around to looking, and many more will open in the next month or two. From my understanding, having affiliation is really important, so keep applying.

Comment: I am applying to earth sciences actually. My original affiliation is physics. I just haven't found that many more that weren't extremely specific in what they were looking for.

Comment: I would recommend adding your specific field to the question as the answer is likely to depend on what you are going into.

Comment: I agree with @SeanEnglish, 20 is a low number in many fields. If you do not find any other adds, you can always directly ask laboratories if they have a position. It also helps if you can say a word or two why you are interested / what can you do to them.

Comment: How many postdocs does the average person apply to?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm from Europe, Horizon 2020, ERC grants and other recognize starting grants as for individuals up to 3 years after PhD to be eligible for postdoc. After that the postdoc experience in academia or industry is already expected.

For me it took personally 8 months to find appropriate job after I submitted PhD thesis - different field (computational biology). I submitted 25 CV, did 4-5 interviews and did also homework to explore different opportunities and laboratories. I had some small money to travel to conferences other sites and I had support from my previous supervisor. Thus I spoke with some heads of labs personally too.

Comment: "ERC grants and other recognize starting grants as for individuals up to 3 years after PhD to be eligible for postdoc" The ERC starting grant is for people who are 2 to 7 years post PhD and who have developed an international profile. It's not a postdoc, most successful applicants are near the end of their 7 years. I know of no hiring definition for post docs working on ERC projects that defines the post doc as within 3 years of PhD...important because I have a starting grant and I'm about to hire a post doc for it. The only rule is that use your university's hiring rules.